# preg_replace #hashtags - non alpa numeric

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am having a problem with the following code:

```
    $input = '#2weeksago #1year&2weeksold #keyword';

    $output = preg_replace('/(?:.^|\s)#(\w+)/', ' <span class="hashtag">#$1</span>', $input);

    print($output);
```

I want each word within a hashtag surrounded with a span-attribute.
This works for the most keywords, but hashtags with a symbol in it doesn't work.

Output

```
 <span class="hashtag">#2weeksago</span> <span class="hashtag">#1year</span>&2weeksold <span class="hashtag">#keyword</span>
```

Can someone help expand this preg_replace?

Comment: What is the desired result, and how to do define “word” to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to break at "word boundaries" but continue with matching till the next white space character, then you need to do exactly that:

```
<?php
$input = '#2weeksago #1year&2weeksold #keyword';
$output = preg_replace('/(?:.^|\s|^)#([^\s]+)/', ' <span class="hashtag">#$1</span>', $input);
print($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
<span class="hashtag">#2weeksago</span> <span class="hashtag">#1year&2weeksold</span> <span class="hashtag">#keyword</span>
```

Comment: Exactly what i need! Thanks